# Is this caused by round-off errors?

Tags: evaluation, linear-algebra

Let's consider this integration

```
Integrate[
 E^(4 n x s) (1 - x)^(-1 + 4 n μ) x^(-1 + 4 n ν), {x, 0, 1}]
```

It returns `Gamma[4 n μ] Gamma[4 n ν] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[
  4 n ν, 4 n (μ + ν), 4 n s]`

Now let's replace those letter by numbers

```
n = 20000;
s = 0.01;
μ = 10^-3;
ν = 10^-3;
```

And let's run both the result of the integral and the integral itself

```
In[28]:= Integrate[
 E^(4 n x s) (1 - x)^(-1 + 4 n μ) x^(-1 + 4 n ν), {x, 0, 1}]

Out[28]= -1.786676093655969*10^352

In[29]:= Gamma[4 n μ] Gamma[
  4 n ν] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[4 n ν, 
  4 n (μ + ν), 4 n s]

Out[29]= 5.20048*10^228
```

The results differ. While I agree both look like big numbers, one is 124 orders of magnitude higher than the other one.

**Given that all calculations were analytic (no numerical approximations) we should find the same results. What causes these different results? Is this difference caused by round-off errors? How can I solve such issues?**

Comment: Yes, I believe it is round-off error.  Try ``s = 0.01`20`` and then ``s = 0.01`200``.

Comment: Btw, what version are you using?  I get different results (V10.0.2, Mac OSX 10.10.1).

Comment: with `s = 0.01`20` I get `0.*10^350` (in red) for the first formula and `5.2004811325650457130*10^228` for the second. I am using `Version 10.0.1.0 in Mac OSX`. I think I had a mistake first. Sorry about that. I corrected my post. Do we still get different results?

Comment: with `s = 0.01`200` I get in both cases some long number times 10 to the power `228`. Seems much better. Was it indeed a round-off error? And the solution is to make to always write the good number of decimal in inputs so to tell Mathematica what degree of precision it should use?

Comment: Now I get the same numbers as in the update. The red in `0.*10^350` means that the precision loss was so great that *M* can only estimate that the result is closer to zero than `10^350` -- a significant loss of precision.  Precision tracking does not occur with `MachinePrecision` numbers such as `s = 0.01`.  Using arbitrary-precision numbers such as ``0.01`20`` etc, which turns on precision tracking, is a way to check calculations that seem off.  I usually increase precision until the result stabilizes.

Comment: see if this gets you a simpler form  `Integrate[  E^(c x) (1 - x)^a x^b, {x, 0, 1},Assumptions->Element[{a,b},Integers]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with numerical error in the procedure used by `Integrate`.  Sufficiently high arbitrary precision, or exact input, is needed to ensure an accurate result from `Integrate`.  On the other hand, `MachinePrecision` is sufficient for `NIntegrate`.  There is nothing particularly numerically challenging about the integrand, so the `NIntegrate` result is not surprising.

Finally, applying [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html) to the exact result to any precision yields an accurate result to the requested precision, as promised in the documentation.  A high precision is not required.

**Insufficient input precision**

```
Block[{n = 20000, s = 0.01, μ = 10^-3, ν = 10^-3},
 Integrate[E^(4 n x s) (1 - x)^(-1 + 4 n μ) x^(-1 + 4 n ν), {x, 0, 1}]
 ]
(*  -1.786676093655969*10^352  *)

Block[{n = 20000, s = 0.01`20, μ = 10^-3, ν = 10^-3},
 Integrate[E^(4 n x s) (1 - x)^(-1 + 4 n μ) x^(-1 + 4 n ν), {x, 0, 1}]
 ]
(*  0.*10^350  *)
```

Given that the answer is about `10^228`, this result suggests that the input needs more than `350 - 228 == 122` digits of precision to get at least one digit of accuracy in the result.

**Sufficient input precision**

122 more digits would be 142; 145 yields 3 digits.

```
Block[{n = 20000, s = 0.01`145, μ = 10^-3, ν = 10^-3},
 Integrate[E^(4 n x s) (1 - x)^(-1 + 4 n μ) x^(-1 + 4 n ν), {x, 0, 1}]
 ]
(*  5.20*10^228  *)
```

Exact input yields an exact answer; applying `N` gives an accurate approximation.

```
Block[{n = 20000, s = 1/100, μ = 10^-3, ν = 10^-3},
 N[Integrate[E^(4 n x s) (1 - x)^(-1 + 4 n μ) x^(-1 + 4 n ν), {x, 0, 1}], 6]
 ]
(*  5.20048*10^228  *)
```

`NIntegrate` gives an accurate answer quickly.  It should be the preferred method for an approximate machine real result.

```
Block[{n = 20000, s = 0.01, μ = 10^-3, ν = 10^-3},
 NIntegrate[E^(4 n x s) (1 - x)^(-1 + 4 n μ) x^(-1 + 4 n ν), {x, 0, 1}]
 ]
(*  5.20048*10^228  *)
```

**Summary**

`NIntegrate` should also be the first method used to check a result from `Integrate` for accuracy.  Stability of the result under increasing precision can be used as a further check.  These are fairly common checks one can find in answers and comments to integration problems on the site.

Answer (score 1):

As stated n the comments, the problem lies with the defnition `s = 0.01` which causes all calculations to be done with machine precision. Higher precision is required, say 20.

Analytic solution

```
int1 = Integrate[E^(4 n x s) (1 - x)^(-1 + 4 n mu) x^(-1 + 4 n nu), {x, 0, 1}]
```

> ConditionalExpression[  Gamma[4 mu n] Gamma[4 n nu]
>   Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[4 n nu,     4 n (mu + nu), 4 n s], Re[n
>   nu] > 0 && Re[mu n] > 0]

Analytic solution evaluated with exact numbers then convered to an approximate number with precision of 20.

```
N[int1 /. {n -> 20000, s -> 1/100, mu -> 10^-3, nu -> 10^-3}, 20]
```

> 5.2004811325650457130*10^228

Integrated with exact numbers then convered to an approximate number with precision of 20

```
Integrate[E^(4 n x s) (1 - x)^(-1 + 4 n mu) x^(-1 + 4 n nu) /. {n -> 20000, 
    s -> 1/100, mu -> 10^-3, nu -> 10^-3}, {x, 0, 1}] // N[#, 20] &
```

> 5.2004811325650457130*10^228

Using exact numbers in integrand then doing numerical ntegation wth working precision of 20

```
NIntegrate[
 E^(4 n x s) (1 - x)^(-1 + 4 n mu) x^(-1 + 4 n nu) /. {n -> 20000, s -> 1/100,
    mu -> 10^-3, nu -> 10^-3}, {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

> 5.2004811325650457130*10^228

Analytic solution evaluated with high precision numbers (minimum precision of 20).

```
int1 /. {n -> 20000, s -> 0.01`20, mu -> 10^-3, nu -> 10^-3}
```

> 5.2004811325650457130*10^228

Numeric integration of high precision integrand (minimum precision of 20).

```
NIntegrate[
 E^(4 n x s) (1 - x)^(-1 + 4 n mu) x^(-1 + 4 n nu) /. {n -> 20000, 
   s -> 0.01`20, mu -> 10^-3, nu -> 10^-3}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

> 5.20048*10^228